# Twitter typeahead on touch devices - what's the deal now?

Tags: javascript, ios, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

So in their own docs they write that ["mobile browsers aren't tested"](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#browser-support) and there are some bug tickets in which it is mentioned, that [mobile browsers aren't supported](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/324) (which isn't quite the same as just "not tested"). In another bug ticket it's said though that it seems to be [compatible with most browsers](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/477).

We have included twitter typeahead 10.5.0 in our project and I can't get it to work on any iOS version/device/browser, even though it seems to work on twitter's example page (which could have implemented a workaround), so bummer. I'm rather furious about how I can't seem to find **anything** on the net about a workaround to support touch devices, like a definitive statement which devices should actually work and/or some clean code examples on how to support touch for twitter's typehead.

So I'm asking you guys now, does anyone know **if** and **on what devices** it should work and maybe has a tip on how to get it to work on touch?
I know I could "just" add some custom touch events on the typeahead elements and execute the same as I do on `typeahead:selected` but I actually really hope there's a cleaner way by using their events/API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so apparently this is a bug with typeahead and fastclick.js which [was introduced in typeahead 0.10.2](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/792), so I needed to downgrade to version 0.10.1 (an upgrade to 0.11 broke our current setup).